# CTMC finding limiting distribution

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

This problem is regarding Continuous time Markov Chains.

I have a rate matrix Q = 
$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -7/12 & 1/3 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/2 & -3/4 & 0 & 1/4 & 0\\
    1/2 & 0 & -5/6 & 0 & 1/3\\
    0 & 0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0\\
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & -1/2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

and initial distribution $\pi^{(0)} $ = (1 0 0 0 0)

I am tasked to find the limiting distribution and I am confused which method to use:

(1):  $\pi^{(0)} \lim_{t\to 0} P_t$, where $P_t$ = $\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(tQ)^k}{k!}$

I tried implementing this method into MATLAB using the expm function for the matrix exponential caluclation, but my MATLAB took too long to calculate, which made me think that this would be a wrong method. My code is as shown below:

```
syms t k 

Q = [-7/12, 1/3, 1/4, 0, 0;
     1/2, -3/4, 0, 1/4, 0;
     1/2, 0, -5/6, 0, 1/3;
     0, 0, 1/2, -1/2, 0;
     0, 1/2, 0, 0, -1/2];

initial_dist = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0];

Pt = symsum(expm(t*Q)/factorial(k),k,0,Inf);

eqn = limit(Pt, t, Inf);

%Limiting Distribution
LD = initial_dist * eqn
```

The second method I tried is this:

(2): $\vec\pi Q$= $\vec 0$

To my understanding, this finds the stationary distribution and cannot be assumed as the limiting distribution.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know conditions under which the stationary distribution equals the limiting distribution? Also, what do you mean by $\vec{\pi}^{(0)} Q = 0$? Do you distinguish between $\vec{\pi}^{(0)}$ and $\pi^{(0)}$?

Comment: @snar i might be wrong but it is when a chain is irreducible, positive recurring and aperiodic? Sorry the $\vec \pi^{(0)}$ was meant to be $\vec \pi$. I've editted it.

Comment: So now you have conditions under which finding the limiting distribution is as difficult as solving a linear system of equations, $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, where $A$ is (in this case) a $5\times 5$ matrix. Can you proceed from there?

Comment: @snar yeap i got it, thanks!

Comment: @WeiXiongYeo If you have found a satisfactory solution to this problem, would you mind typing it up as an answer and accepting it? That is the general etiquette in this situation; it leaves one less unanswered question on the site, and also makes the page more useful in the event that someone finds it during a search.